# Printing text with more than one character in Objective C

Tags: objective-c

I'm finding this a bit counter intuitive. If I want to do the equivalent of scanf and assign that input to a variable or array how do I do that and then print it in objective-c.

Comment: Not easily. The closes thing available in objective-c APIs is JSON parsing, which doesn't make sense in a lot of situations, so you are probably best off creating a C-array of `ids`, parsing each, and then using `[NSArray arrayWithObjects: count:]`.

Comment: write this code 
for(int i = 0; i<[arr count]; i++){
nslog(%@,[arr objectatindex:i]);
}

Comment: Please check my posted answer :)

Comment: Whoa. So to take this input and then to print it is kind of mad complicated.

Answer (score -1):

You can use NSMutableArray and loop each character in NSString test that you have then use
I have already tested it ..

```
NSMutableArray *arr = [[NSMutableArray alloc] init];
NSString *str = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"masdasdada"];
int length = [str length];

for (int i = 0 ; i < length; i++) {
    NSLog(@"%hu",[str characterAtIndex:i]);

    unichar utf8char = [str characterAtIndex:i]; 
    char chars[2];
    int len = 1;

    if (utf8char > 127) {
        chars[0] = (utf8char >> 8) & (1 << 8) - 1;
        chars[1] = utf8char & (1 << 8) - 1; 
        len = 2;
    } else {
        chars[0] = utf8char;
    }

    NSString *string = [[NSString alloc] initWithBytes:chars
                                                length:len 
                                              encoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding];

    NSLog(@"%@",string);
    [arr addObject:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@",string]];
}

for (NSMutableString *s in arr) {
    NSLog(@"%@",s);
}
```

Comment: Great, but that doesn't help with him reading the array input. You only answered half of the question, and you answered the easy part. -1.

Comment: Thanks for your notice i think that i have miss understanding the question and i have edited my answer to make it print every character in NSString.. :)

Comment: No, you completely misread the question. The OP was asking for a way to create a NSMutableArray from an input like one you would get from `scanf`, not how to output it